# Operator keyword used in an unexpected manner in a function

Tags: c++

I ran across this code recently which is part of a template class:

```
operator T*();
```

I have been unable to find a clarification on this on SO or online. I have been unable to figure out how this declaration is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an implicit cast operator that allows the object to be converted to a T*.

For instance :

```
template<typename T>
class arrayOf10T
{
    T data[10];

    operator T*()
    {
        return data;
    }
};
```

Allows you to cast an arrayOfT into an int* like this :

```
int* ptr = arrayOf10T<int>;
```

Answer (score 2):

This declares an *implicit conversion* from the class’ type to `T*` (that is, pointer to `T`).

With such an operator, your class (let’s call it `foo`) can be used as follows:

```
foo<int> f;
int *i = f; // calls f.operator int*()
```

Comment: @Nawaz, I made the edit without which this answer makes no sense. If @Konrad wishes to revert or further edit, he's free to do so.

Comment: @JSBangs Uaaargh, my eyes! The `*` belongs to the type in C++! Anyway, thanks for the correction. ;-)

Comment: I actually agree. I only went with `int *i` (rather than `int* i`) because that's what Nawaz suggested.

Comment: +1 Yet another feature that was taught in programming lectures, never used it and forgot about it.